# How do you access android permissions in c#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm building an application for android using Unity and I need to access permissions in the phone.

So far I've been able to reference camera and microphone, but there doesn't seem to be references for the other two permissions; storage and telephone. How do I access them?

```cs
 void OnGUI()
    {
        //microphone
        #if PLATFORM_ANDROID
        if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.Microphone))
        {
            dialog.AddComponent<PermissionsRationaleDialog>();

        }
        if (!Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.Camera))
        {
            dialog.AddComponent<PermissionsRationaleDialog>();

        }
        else if (dialog != null)
        {
            Destroy(dialog);
        }
        #endif
    }
```

As you can see permission and camera have reference but I can't find anywhere on the internet that has the solution to this.

Comment: Try the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See in your code Permission.Microphone is actually a String. So you can use and directly the permission as if you use in Android Manifest.

This one Can be used to get the Android Storage Read and Write Permission.(Write Permission Implies Read Permission also)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Android;

public class RequestPermissionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
         if (Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite))
         {
            // The user authorized use of the microphone.
         }
         else
         {
             // We do not have permission to use the microphone.
             // Ask for permission or proceed without the functionality enabled.
             Permission.RequestUserPermission(Permission.ExternalStorageWrite);
         }
    }
}
```

This is What is said in Unity Documentation For Requesting Permission in Android

> A string that describes the permission to request. For permissions
>   which Unity has not predefined you may also manually provide the
>   constant value obtained from the Android documentation here:
>   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups
>   such as "android.permission.READ_CONTACTS".

That means instead of using `permission.ExternalStorageWrite` you may directly use `"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"`. Similarly for any other permission that is available on Android platform.

For Telephone permission the Unity doesn't have a built-in constant defined so you need to use that permission as if we use in android. Here am just giving an example for requesting permissions for reading contacts. As I did not exactly understood what you actually meant by telephone permission. Unity has nothing to do with Android Permission these are actually set of permission strings that are understood by Android. So for some standard permissions that are most often used unity have some predefined constant string values. That is actually for ease of use for developers.

```
public class RequestPermissionScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
         if (Permission.HasUserAuthorizedPermission("android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"))
         {
            // The user authorized use of the microphone.
         }
         else
         {
             // We do not have permission to use the microphone.
             // Ask for permission or proceed without the functionality enabled.
             Permission.RequestUserPermission("android.permission.READ_CONTACTS");
         }
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your issue. Thank You.